# What is the difference between Boeing 777-31H and Boeing 777-31H(ER)?

Tags: boeing, boeing-777

What exactly is the difference between a B777-31H and B777-31H(ER)? Is ER the latest version of 777-31H?

Comment: ER stands for extended range, which means added tanks and reinforcing the rest of the craft to hold all the fuel

Comment: and potentially weight savings elsewhere

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 777-31H is a standard Boeing 777-300 manufactured for Emirates (customer code 1H).

The 777-31H(ER) is a Boeing 777-300ER (Extended Range) again for Emirates.

Compared to the standard 777-300, the 777-300ER has:

- A longer range due to the extra fuel it can carry (145538 kg compared to 135880 kg for the -300 baseline)
- A higher Operating Empty Weight (167829 kg compared to 159570 kg for the -300 baseline)
- A higher Maximum Take-Off Weight (351535 kg compared to 299370 kg for the -300 baseline)
- A higher maximum structural payload weight (69853 kg compared to 64960 kg for the -300 baseline)
- A wider wingspan (64.80 compared to 60.93 m)
- A different engine delivering more thrust

The Boeing 777-300ER is always equipped with General Electric GE90-115BL1 engines, while the baseline -300 can be ordered with four different engine models from General Electric, Pratt& Whitney or Rolls Royce. The Emirates Boeing 777-300 aircraft have the Rolls Royce RR Trent 892 engines installed. They deliver 415 kN of thrust, almost 100 kN less than the GE90-115BL1 engines.

Answer (score -1):

B777-31H(ER) can fly further than B777-31H.

Comment: welcome to Aviation.se. While your answer is correct, it lacks detail, could you please edit your post to add more information?